# Container, fragment rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, rotation, runtimeexception

I have an activity `ContainerOfReports`, that contain references to two fragments. When I rotate the phone I got the below exception-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.salary/com.example.salary.MainScreens.Fragments.ContainerOfReports}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.salary.MainScreens.Fragments.MonthsFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
```

So, to resolve it I decided to initialize `savedInstanceState = null`. It solved the problem, but I think it's not a good solution. Maybe someone have know better solution for this kind of problem. Thanks.

```
public class ContainerOfReports extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MonthsFragmentContainer";
    private Context context;
    private BottomNavigationView botNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monthly_container);

        initializeObjects();
        initializeSupportFragment(new MonthsFragment(context));
    }

    private void initializeObjects() {
        context = this;
        botNav = findViewById(R.id.detailsBotNav);
        botNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        botNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    }

    private void initializeSupportFragment(Fragment nextFragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    //Checking which fragment to display to user
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            initializeSupportFragment(checkWhichFragmentSelected(item));
            return true;
        }
    };



    private Fragment checkWhichFragmentSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.fragReport:
                return new DetailReportFragment(context);
            default:
                return new MonthsFragment(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }


}
```